# argument validation in clap v4

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, clap

I am using crate [`clap`](https://crates.io/crates/clap) v4。When I try to write something validating arguments against regex, I had some problem with lifetimes.

- Document of [ValueParser](https://docs.rs/clap/4.0.32/clap/builder/struct.ValueParser.html) for convenience

My code as following:

```
pub fn validator_regex(r: &'static str) -> ValueParser {
    ValueParser::from(move |s: &str| -> std::result::Result<&str, Error> {
        let reg = regex::Regex::new(r).unwrap();
        match reg.is_match(s) {
            true => Ok(s),
            false => Err(Error::from(format!("not matches {}", r))),
        }
    })
}

pub fn validator_identifier() -> ValueParser {
    validator_regex("^[-_0-9a-zA-Z]+$")
}
```

And compilation error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> main\./src\cmd\cmd_util.rs:440:21
    |
437 |     ValueParser::from(move |s: &str| -> std::result::Result<&str, Error> {
    |                                -                            - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'2`
    |                                |
    |                                let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
440 |             true => Ok(s),
    |                     ^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

Could any help me on these two questions:

- how to validate regex in clap v4
- why there' s `lifetime may not live long enough` error in this code, since the returned `&str` lives as long as the closure argument, and this can be compiled normally

```
pub fn validator_regex(r: &'static str) -> impl Fn(&str) -> Result<&str, String> {
    move |s: &str| -> Result<&str, String> {
        let reg = regex::Regex::new(r).unwrap();
        match reg.is_match(s) {
            true => Ok(s),
            false => Err(format!("not match {}", r)),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the `From` impl you're invoking:

```rust
impl<P> From<P> for ValueParser
where
    P: TypedValueParser + Send + Sync + 'static,
```

Ok, take a look at `TypedValueParser`:

```rust
impl<F, T, E> TypedValueParser for F
where
    F: Fn(&str) -> Result<T, E> + Clone + Send + Sync + 'static,
    E: Into<Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>>,
    T: Send + Sync + Clone,
```

So, the signature is not `Fn(&str) -> Result<&str, E>`, it is `<T> Fn(&str) -> Result<T, E>`. Is it different? Can't we just put `&str` in the place of `T`?

It is *very* different. Let's annotate the lifetimes:

```
// Fn(&str) -> Result<&str, E>
for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> Result<&'a str, E>

// <T> Fn(&str) -> Result<T, E>
<&'b str> for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> Result<&'b str, E>
```

Where does `'b` come from? It can't be HRTB, as it is declared in the `impl` header (`T`) and not the trait bound (`Fn`). Therefore, it must be a fixed lifetime. See the mismatch? The lifetimes I called `'a` and `'b` are what the compiler calls `'1` and `'2`, respectively. If `'b` is fixed, it cannot be derived from the dynamic HRTB `'a`.

The fix is simple: just don't return `&str`, return `String` instead:

```rust
pub fn validator_regex(r: &'static str) -> ValueParser {
    ValueParser::from(move |s: &str| -> std::result::Result<String, Error> {
        let reg = regex::Regex::new(r).unwrap();
        match reg.is_match(s) {
            true => Ok(s.to_owned()),
            false => Err(Error::from(format!("not matches {}", r))),
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I wonder if there is any way that I can return an `&str` in ValueParser ?

Comment: I found that `String`s are used in clap examples, which is a lot different from v3. Maybe it's because lifetimes are removed in v4. Anyway, thanks.